# MySQL Query: output all players villages by coordinates

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with a query. You are given the tables: player (playerID (primary key), playerName) and village (villageID, villageName, x, y, population, playerID (foreign key) and check that x in y is between -400 and 400).

The task is to write a query, where the output is players names, who have ALL of their villages between 100 and 200 on x, and 0 and 100 on y.

Currently i have this query, but it doesnt look for ALL of the villages.

```
SELECT i.playerName
FROM player i JOIN
     village n
     USING(playerID) 
WHERE (n.x BETWEEN 100 AND 200) AND (n.y BETWEEN 0 AND 100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want *all* the villages, then you need to compare all rows.  This suggests aggregation:

```
SELECT i.playerName
FROM igralec i JOIN
     naselje n
     USING (playerID) 
GROUP BY i.playerName
HAVING SUM( (n.x BETWEEN 100 AND 200) AND (n.y BETWEEN 0 AND 100) ) = COUNT(*);
```

The `HAVING` clause is guaranteeing that all rows (i.e. cities) meet the condition for a given player.